# Orchard CMS update record directly in database

Tags: orchardcms

I have got list of content items , for each content items I need to add a meta keyword and descriptions. I am using VandelayIndustries module for this. I have got list of keywords and descriptions along with the contentItemId .I can find out the published ContentItem from ContentItemVersionRecord.

Is there a way I can directly insert record in Vandelay_Industries_MetaRecord table with Id as ContentItemId and keywords and Descriptions.

Comment: What do mean by 'directly'? Orchard has a code first approach, so you should use the ContentManager to insert records. What do you intend to achieve?

Comment: I have got list of (meta content)keywords and Descriptions  in a csv file. I  need to attach these tags to content items from csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create an import method. Your ContentItems should have a `MetaPart`. You can achieve this either by going to Content Definition in the Orchard dashboard or by modifing the ContentType in the migrations.

```cs
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MyContentType",
            type => type
                .WithPart("MetaPart"));
```

Create a method that iterates thru the csv file and will add the entries:

```cs
foreach(var entry in listFromFile) {
    var item = _contentManager.Get(entry.Id).As<MediaPart>();
    item.Key = entry.Key;
    item.Description = entry.Description;
}
```

And that's it.